# Side by side chart with Line chart (Multiple measures on same axis)

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to create side by side bar chart with the line chart on the same axis. My X-axis shows months of the year with the new cases and completed cases as bar charts and I need to overlay it with the Turn around Time as a line chart.
[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLyop.jpg)
The data provided has different case status (New, Open & Resolved) and the starting date for the cases. I need to create calculated fields to count the number of new and completed cases and display it in the side by side bar chart. I am connected to a live data source. So, I think pivot is not an option for me as it is not getting displayed when I do a right click on Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau is unable to natively build a side-by-side with lines due to how side-by-side charts are built - each cohort holds the cluster of bar charts, so the lines will only be continuous within a cluster.
That said, this can be done easy enough. Take a look at chart 37 and its accompanying video demonstrating how to build this from my how to page: [Datawonders | Show Me](https://datawonders.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TABLEAU/pages/294914/Show+me+how+to+build+that)

The workbook is downloadable too

Steve